# str_replace not responding in functions.php

Tags: php, functions

I'm tring to use `str_replace` within a wordpress function but its not working.

My code:

```
function fields($content) {
    if(is_feed()) {  
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $url = str_replace('http://', '', '' . get_post_meta($post_id, 'book-author', true) . ''); 
    $output = '<div>';
    $output .= '' .url. '';
    $output .= '</div>';
    $content = $content.$output;  
    }  
    return $content;  
}
add_filter('the_content','fields');
```

What I'm getting in result of `' .url. '` is just "url" printed in my feed. Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: You are not using url as variable, like this `$url`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could not work, you simply miss the $ before $url.
    $output .= '' .$url. '';

Comment: Why you need single quotes?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly assign the url variable to the output variable as below.

```
$output .= $url;
```